# A single EntityType generating a big set of queries

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to provide a selection with >300 choices

```
$form->add('products', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => Product::class,
    'query_builder' => function (ProductRepository $er) use ($customerId) {
        return $er->QBByCustomer($customerId);
    },
    'choice_label' => 'l.name',
));
```

The QueryBuilder:

```
public function QBByCustomer($customer = null)
{
    return $this->QB()
        ->addSelect('p.name AS HIDDEN name')
        ->join('p.customer', 'c')
        ->join('p.label', 'l')
        ->where('c.customer = :customer')
        ->setParameter('customer', $customer)
        ->addOrderBy('name')
    ;
}
```

When I render the form, Doctrine generates **>300 queries** to load each related objects.

Is there a way to tell Doctrine to use the labels from the QueryBuilder I gave, instead of firing as much query as selectable items ?

Comment: can you show one of this query? What are they looking for?

Comment: Show the code and mapping of the Product entity.

Comment: i suggest the following: make use of the fetch="extra_lazy" on the entity relationship ,the use of ','multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true'

Comment: Ok, I found that I'm using the label of a linked entity. I'm going to try to use partial loading here

Answer (score 2):

Since the displayed label is fetched from a linked entity (`label`), we have to help Doctrine to load it.

Here is how the QueryBuilder should look like:

```
'query_builder' => function (ProductRepository $er) use ($customerId) {
    $qb = $er->QBByCustomer($customerId);
    $qb->addSelect('partial p.{id}');
    $qb->addSelect('partial l.{id, name}');
    return $qb;
},
'choice_label' => 'label.name',
```